# Computing a SecretHash for AWS Cognito User Pool API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android, amazon-cognito

The [AWS Cognito SignUp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html) API requires computing a `SecretHash`.

The `SecretHash` is a Base 64-encoded keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC) calculated using the secret key of a user pool client and username plus the client ID in the message. The specific HMAC algorithm is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash).

I ported that java example to C# so that I can call the SignUp API from a Xamarin.Android application to signup a user to a AWS User Pool from an Android device (See code below).

The `SecretHash` is supposed to have the following pattern `[\w+=/]+`. This is documented in the SignUp API.

When I execute my code, I obtain a `SecretHash` which does not follow that pattern precisely, so there is a problem with my C# implementation. I can't figure out what that problem is. When I call the SignUp API, AWS responds with an `InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'secretHash' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w+=/]+`

```
string CalculateSecretHash(string userPoolClientId, string userPoolClientSecret, string userName)
{
    const string HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

    var signingKey = new Javax.Crypto.Spec.SecretKeySpec(
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userPoolClientSecret),
        HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);

    var mac = Javax.Crypto.Mac.GetInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.Init(signingKey);
        mac.Update(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName));

    byte[] rawHmac = mac.DoFinal(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userPoolClientId));

    return Base64.EncodeToString(rawHmac, Base64Flags.Default);
}
```

This yields `SecretHash` that follow the following pattern: `\w+=` not quite `[\w+=/]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future readers, replacing `Base64Flags.Default` with `Base64Flags.NoWrap` has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with this simpler version:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
```

```
        private string CreateSecretHash(string username, string userPoolClientId, string userPoolClientSecret)
        {
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var clientIdBytes = encoding.GetBytes(username + userPoolClientId);
            var clientSecretBytes = encoding.GetBytes(userPoolClientSecret);
            var base64Str = "";
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(clientSecretBytes))
            {
                var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(clientIdBytes);
                base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
            return base64Str;
        }
```